# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am following the example from [this site](http://www.geekbeing.com/2012/05/18/implement-live-web-chat-part-1) to try and implement a live web chat application. I am very new to javascript to jquery, so I thought I'd just copy the example and learn as I go and add things.

This is the code that I am using:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "OnlineUsers";
}


<html>
<head>
    <title>Online Users</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.4/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.4/leaflet.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="upperPanel">
            <div>
                <ul id="messages" itemid="@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name">

                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="friends">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottomPanel">
            <textarea rows="2" cols="100" id="chatMessage"></textarea>
            <input id="chatSubmitMessage" type="submit" value="Send" style="margin-left: 10px;" /><br />  
        </div>
    </div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var pusher = new window.Pusher('0b7eeff567653e170094');
            var channel = pusher.subscribe('chat_channel');
            channel.bind('message_received', function (data) {
                $("#messages").
                append('<li>' + data.user + ' ' + data.message + ' ' + data.timestamp + '</li>');
            });

            $('#chatSubmitMessage').bind('click', function () {
                $.post("/", {
                    chatMessage: $('#chatMessage').val(),
                    username: $('#messages').attr('itemid')
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

This code gives me the following error in the Chrome debugger:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
(anonymous function)
fire jquery-1.8.2.js:974
self.add jquery-1.8.2.js:1018
jQuery.fn.jQuery.ready jquery-1.8.2.js:246
jQuery.fn.jQuery.init jquery-1.8.2.js:174
jQuery jquery-1.8.2.js:44
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function) jquery-1.8.2.js:564
jQuery.extend.globalEval jquery-1.8.2.js:565
(anonymous function) jquery-1.8.2.js:6006
jQuery.extend.each jquery-1.8.2.js:611
jQuery.fn.extend.domManip jquery-1.8.2.js:5991
jQuery.fn.extend.append jquery-1.8.2.js:5764
jQuery.fn.(anonymous function) jquery-1.8.2.js:6186
$.ajax.success jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js:3685
fire jquery-1.8.2.js:974
self.fireWith jquery-1.8.2.js:1082
done jquery-1.8.2.js:7788
callback
```

I'm assuming the error has something to do with the function being unnamed, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And each of those posts has an answer for a different specific situation, I thought someone with a trained eye might be able to spot my error much quicker than browsing through 1000s of posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not loading jquery, but trying to use it. Add this to your head

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tried this, but still get the same error. Doesn't an mvc 4 project automatically include jquery? The Layout.cshtml file contains @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/jquerymobile")

Comment: This was the main problem after all, however just adding jQuery didn't solve it as other missing dependencies (as pointed out by Vinay) also returned the same error. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you included the Pusher code? Make sure by opening up the web inspector and trying to see if window.Pusher is not actually undefined. If it isn't defined, [include Pusher and its dependencies to the head of your file](http://pusher.com/tutorials/realtime_chat_widget). Let me know if that was your problem. It's hard to tell with what's given in the question.

Comment: You helped me find the problem as multiple dependencies weren't included. I downloaded the example solution and noticed that he had included them in the shared Layout file and not in the posted example. +1 for helping me, but Pastor Bones answered first. Thanks for the help :)