# JQuery - loading page into div - anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo, anonymous-function

I am trying to load a page into a div when the user presses a link. However in the dev console (Chrome) I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
(anonymous function)
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
  <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/common.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.2/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async:true, parseOnLoad:true"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/common.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/DyContent.js"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bannerColor"></div>
    <div id="imgNav">
      <img id="banner" src="Images/logoLast.jpg"/> 
      <ul id="nav">
        <li class="current"><a "View/index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#About">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Login">Login/Register</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#Add">Add/Remove Car</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Search">Serach Invoices</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Book">Book Service</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Contact" id="Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="centerPane" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My JQuery file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#Contact').click(function () {
    $('#centerPane').load('External/map.php');
  });
});
```

and the page I am trying to load (map.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/common.css" />
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/location.js"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header></header>
    <div id="mapContainer"></div>
    <div id="writtenDir"></div>
   <footer></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is it that is causing the error and not allowing the div to be populated?

EDIT:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://scmweb.infj.ulst.ac.uk/~B00518833/DNA/View/CSS/common.css" />
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://scmweb.infj.ulst.ac.uk/~B00518833/DNA/View/JS/location.js"></script>
<div id="mapContainer"></div>
<div id="writtenDir"></div>
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery in your parent file (not map.php)?

Comment: Did you include JQuery on the page you are trying to run `load`?

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery? Silly question, I know. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217185/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function

Comment: Yes. `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I can include the full HTML page code if you like?

Comment: It would help if you posted the rest of the markup for your main document.

Comment: @Colin747 sorry what's the content and the full path of this file *External/map.php* ? can you access this file by browser?

Comment: First verify if the onclick handler is called.

Comment: and did you tryed with full url?

Comment: Yes I did, I got the same error.

Comment: also i don't think loading <doctype> and all html stuffs like head into other <doctype> is a good practice did you tryed loading just an element to test it?

Comment: @Raghav It is being called, I added in an alert if it is click and it alerted out fine.

Comment: It might be because you have other javascript libraries as well. "Undefined is not a function" error is usually thrown in the case of namespace conflict. As I mentioned previously, first verify if onclick handler is called - This will verify jquery is working fine

Comment: Try loading the jQuery file before dojo

Comment: See my last comment, it is being called fine.

Comment: It loads a `<p>` element fine as well. @Badaboooooom

Comment: @Colin747 so it loads a *p* element but not *<doctype>* etc ?

Comment: Yea, just had the `<p>` and nothing else. @Badaboooooom

Comment: associate a callback function as well in the load() function call. Verify the data received. Alternately, in firebug check the network call

Comment: why don't you remove <doctype> and other html stuffs not needed so?

Comment: @Badaboooooom I then get the following error. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null `

Comment: Yeah it looks like you just need the snippet anyway?

Comment: Can you post the updated php code you are using now after removing html stuff including all external JS calls

Comment: Edited my original post. `Getting this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
(anonymous function)`

Comment: Include the CSS link as part of the main page itself. As for the scripts link them in the main file itself. If this is not possible you have to evaluate the scripts present as part of the response yourself. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234014/how-to-load-the-jquery-responsehtml-page-with-script-tags-into-the-dom (or) use jquery.getScript() to evaluate the scripts

Comment: So would I just put: `$.getScript("path/script.js");` in the function that I am using to load the content onclick?

Comment: yes. First try loading a basic HTML content first then bring in the interactive elements.

Comment: Got it working! If you want to post that all into an answer I'll happily accept! @Raghav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consolidating all my comments as a single answer:

This might be because you have other javascript libraries as well. "Undefined is not a function" error is usually thrown in the case of namespace conflict.
First verify if the onclick handler is called - This will verify jquery is working fine.

If it is getting called, associate a callback function as well in the load() function call. Verify if the data received. 
Alternately, in firebug check the network call.

If this is working fine as well, then include the CSS link as part of the main page itself.
As for the scripts, link them in the main file itself. If this is not possible ,you have to evaluate the scripts present as part of the response yourself. 
Refer [how to load the Jquery response(HTML page with script tags) into the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234014/how-to-load-the-jquery-responsehtml-page-with-script-tags-into-the-dom) (or) use jquery.getScript() to evaluate the scripts.
Try loading a basic HTML content first then bring in the interactive elements

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is to edit your map.js so that it does not include a complete html page but just what you need :

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/location.js"></script>

<header></header>
<div id="mapContainer"></div>
<div id="writtenDir"></div>
<footer></footer>
```

If you load your file like you do, you would end up having something like that in your document :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
    <head> 
        [....]
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="centerPane" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'">
            <!DOCTYPE html> 
            <html lang="en"> 
               <head>[...]</head>
               <body>[...]</body>
            </html>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Wich is obviously not valid html , and maybe can cause some script errors...

### Edit

As pointed by Colin you already tried removing extra doctype and html (I didn't read all 22 comments), but you then had a completely different error :

```
@Badaboooooom I then get the following error. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null – Colin747 58 mins ago
```

Wich is probably a completely different problem. Other code has been executed.

I would first remove doctypes and all scripts of your map.js, then when add the script functionality one by one to debug them.

Comment: Might want to read the comments, already been tried with errors.

Comment: @Colin747 : with a _different_ error. That obviously solves part of the problem. If other scripts breaks later, that's another story.

Comment: I got it solved in the last few comments, thanks for the help though.